# How to get x and y coordinates of an element in protractor Node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor

I am trying to get the x, y coordinates of an element in protractor Node.js. But it is returning the object.

```
this.dragAnddrop=function (LocatorFrom,LocatorTo ) {
  var xCoord=LocatorFrom.getLocation();
  var yCoord=LocatorTo.getLocation();
  console.log("The  location is "+xCoord+"and "+ yCoord);
}
```

output:

> ```
>   The  location is [object Object]and [object Object]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

right, because this is expected. positions of elements on the page have 2 coordinates: `x` and `y`. According to protractor's page the results of [.getLocation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getLocation) is an object like this:

```
{
 x: 15,
 y: 20
}
```

So if to get x or y you should do this

```
var coords = LocatorFrom.getLocation();
console.log('x coord', coords.x)
console.log('y coord', coords.y)
```